# Methods for detecting liquid drops with phototransistor

Tags: arduino, signal-processing, circuit

ECE people: I have a simple circuit with an LED pointing at a phototransistor. There is a tube in between them that drops of liquid will drip through at random times. I am reading the voltage with an Arduino at the emitter as it drops when the LED is occluded.

Non-ECE people: I am reading in near constant values every time through the Arduino loop. Every once in a while this value may change for some unknown number of loops. I want to increment a counter every time this happens and avoid multiple counts.

I have tried a few methods of my own (e.g. averages last some number of values and checking for different averages) but they seem to be pretty unstable. I'm not an expert at signal processing or anything, but I was wondering what some good methods/algorithms would be for this kind of thing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: first calibrate the photoresistor.

Comment: What? Who said there was a photoresistor?

Comment: oh sty.. mis-read the post

Comment: is noise a problem? or is counting a problem?

Comment: There aren't any problems yet. I imagine noise will be one. I just wanted some advice on methods to use.

Comment: to get rid of noise you can use a low pass filter. I think that should do.

Answer (score 0):

This a a short function to update the count of drops detected till now.

```
int UpdateCount (int current, int old, int count) // current is current value of phototransisor, old is the old value
    if ((current==1)&(old==0)){
        return count count+1
    }
}
```

This function takes in "filtered" current and old values of the phototransistor and based on the values updates the count.

To implement a low pass filter, refer to low-pass-filter on wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter). You will get an expression which you can easily code.

I believe these two sub-solution on integration solve your problem.